# Getting an error code 0x800704cf when trying to sign in to excel 365

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, microsoft-excel, wireless-networking

Everytime I open an excel file, it prompt me to sign in because my cached credentials have expired and every time I try to sign in, it give me a message that says

> it doesn't look like you're connected to the internet...

and an error code of `0x800704cf` , but my device is connected to internet.

[Sign-in error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3St3R.png)

Excel is seems not the only exception, I also can't sign in with my account to microsoft store and switch from local account to microsoft account in my system account info, but I have no trouble signing(unlink and link) to my onedrive app.

I did the suggested solutions in theses following sites/video:

https://digiworthy.com/2020/10/10/fix-error-code-0x800704cf-windows-10/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j9sp6nw5Qzk

I also did network reset and `sfc /scannow` and switch from wifi to cable, but still not fix.

All devices(including mine) that connected to the same router shows this message when I troubleshoot the network adapter

> Your computer appears to be correctly configured, but the device or
> resource(DNS server) is not responding

[Detection message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cs3ma.png)

But somehow my device, is the only suffers from this error code 0x800704cf , other devices can sign out and sign in with their microsoft accounts to excel, so I can't say that these two errors are related to each other

My device windows specs/version
Edition: windows 10 Pro
Version: 21H1
OS build: 19043.1526
Experience: Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.4170.0

Comment: Try to create a new account and check if it has this problem.

Comment: Are you able to log into your microsoft account from your browser? Can you see your 365 subscription? If its not an authentication / sub issue, it might be your router setup. Did you ever try changing DNS servers for use with VPN / geolocation services? Try changing the DNS server in your router or as a test just for your windows pc to 8.8.8.8 and/or 8.8.4.4 (free public google DNS servers). Don't forget to write down your current DNS settings and/or verify with your ISP.

Comment: Please indicate if your account is associated with a Microsoft 365 Home (personal/family) or Business (enterprise) subscription.